# Receiving broadcast from service to appWidgetProvider

Tags: android, xamarin, broadcastreceiver, android-widget, android-service

I have a custom `appWidgetProvider` that receives different system broadcasts.(bluetooth and wifi state change and etc.)

As long as there is no action for `FlashLight` state change, I added custom one.

So I'm trying to send a broadcast with custom action from `service` to `appWidgetProvider` but can't really work it out.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Label = "Root Manager")]
[IntentFilter(new string[] 
    {
        RootWidget.FlashWidget, "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE", 
        BluetoothAdapter.ActionStateChanged, WifiManager.WifiStateChangedAction
    })]    
[MetaData("android.appwidget.provider", Resource = "@xml/bt_widget")]
public class RootWidget : AppWidgetProvider
{
    public static Camera camera;
    public const string FlashWidget = "com.flashlight.STATE_CHANGED";

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // some code

            UpdateWidget(context);

        // some code           
    }

    private void UpdateWidget(Context context)
    {
        // some code 

        if (camera.GetParameters().FlashMode == Camera.Parameters.FlashModeTorch)
        {
            Intent flashIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(DisableFlashService));
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetService(context, 0, flashIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
            remoteViews.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.flash, pendingIntent);
        }
        else
        {
            Intent flashIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(EnableFlashService));
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetService(context, 0, flashIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
            remoteViews.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.flash, pendingIntent);
        }

        // some code
    }
}
```

Services:

```
[Service]
    class EnableFlashService : IntentService
    {
        protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
        {            
            // turn on flash

            Intent widgetIntent = new Intent(RootWidget.FlashWidget);
            SendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }


    [Service]
    class DisableFlashService : IntentService
    {
        protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            // turn off flash

            Intent widgetIntent = new Intent(RootWidget.FlashWidget);
            SendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }
```

To sum up, I want `RootWidget` to receive broadcast with custom action sent from service.